# Error al abrir una web desde google Chrome/Edge, pero si abre en IExplorer. ( window.parent.frames is not a function)

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

cordial saludo. me podrian ayudar con el error que me sale Uncaught TypeError: window.parent.frames is not a function al intentar abrir un aplicativo web en Google Chrome/Edge. Este sitio si abre de forma correcta en IExplorer. donde quiero cargar una seccion html la referencia con href, pero donde requiero cargar un pdf me sale error. En internet explorer todo carga de forma correcta. De antemano gracias por sus aportes.

Comment: ¿Y dónde está el código?

Answer (score 0):

Solucionado.
Para mi caso solo tenia que cambiar ("") por [""].
window.parent.frames[""].location.replace(""). De esta forma funciona correctamente en Google y Edge. Tambien deberia servir para google  Mozilla.

Slds.

Comment: Está bien que lo hayas solucionado, pero la próxima vez si haces una pregunta pon al menos el código que falla.